# Efficient way to prevent browse URL submit

Tags: php

I have a button on page which calls a php file like below:

```
message_sql.inc.php?act=delete&message_id=1
```

Is there an efficient way to prevent running the url directly from the browser and only allowing it when called from a script?

Comment: Are you looking for and [XmlHttpRequest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 2):

What you try is not a really good idea. You should use `POST` requests to submit delete forms and save them with a token for example.

And you should save your script with a session and a login. That no one can submit that directly.